# Do I really need to check for null in Validators?

Tags: jsf-2

I read somewhere that as of JSF 2.0, validator routines are required to properly handle the condition where the value parameter is null.  So I just wrote this validate method that looks like this:

```
public void validateTandC(FacesContext context, UIComponent source, Object value) {
    if (value == null || !(value instanceof Boolean)) {
        FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                "Terms and Conditions Not Accepted", "Value Not Present");
        throw new ValidatorException(fm);
    }
    if (((Boolean) value) != true) {
        FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "Terms and Condistions Not Accepted",
                "You must check the box that confirms you accept the Terms and Condtions ");
        throw new ValidatorException(fm);
    }
}
```

This is a rather tedious construction, given that this method is ONLY referred to in an associated page and ONLY from a single **h:selectBooleanCheckbox**.  If that is the case why would the first **if** statement ever resolve to true?   Would an NPE ever happen in real life if I didn't have it?

Comment: Related: [Validate required checkbox](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/09/validate-required-checkbox.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, a property which is binded to `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` component will never be null. If you don't check the box, it will be `false` and vice versa. Hence, you don't need to check for `null` in your `Validator`.

Besides, for any other `UIInput` components, I believe you can simply set their `required` attribute to `true` and `null` case will automatically be handled for you. For example,

```
<h:inputText id="myInput" required="true" requiredMessage="Hey yo! Type something here." />
<h:message for="myInput" />
```

If a user missed the above text box, he would see `Hey yo! Type something here.` message after clicking submit.

Comment: This was the "validation" (no pun intended) I was looking for.   I am not sure about the required attribute.  When I had required="true" and a validator="#{bean.myValidator}" I ended up with some behavior I couldn't understand.   I didn't look into it that much but I'll go back land look again.

Comment: @AlanObject `required` & `validator` attributes should not give any troubles to each other. Anyway, you can always create a new question if you have any problems :).

Answer (score 1):

If the `value` is `null`, then `!(value instanceof Boolean)` will also return `true` (`null` isn't an instance of a `Boolean`).

So you can simplify this to eliminate the `value == null` portion of your check without changing the functionality or having to worry about a NPE - eliminating your "tedious construction":

```
if (!(value instanceof Boolean)) {
```

Comment: You're right about that.  I end up typing a lot of clauses in my statements that are redundant out of bad habit.